# Issue with ansible logic to patch system

Tags: ansible, centos7, patch

I am updating my CentOS role to patch systems after Frozen repos have been configured and non-Frozen repos are removed. I am finding that, if use the logic below, it restores the CentOS repos after ansible already removed them:

`- name: Patch the System
  yum:
    name: '*'
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest`

If I remove the task above, the CentOS repos don't regenerate. What am I missing? Is there additional logic or a more efficient way to patch systems?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by breaking out "find and removing non-frozen repo files" into separate task file that is called unconditional before patching and conditional after patching (when task reports a change)

Answer (score -1):

What this does is that it checks if there are updates available (it is comparable with apt-get update) and then install/updates all(*) packages to the latest version

Comment: Looks like the CentOS repos are being regenerated when centos-release is updated. Maybe I need to exclude this package from the task in question and handle it separately?